# how to resolve code signing warning while making archive file to test on ios device?

Tags: codesign

i got warning like Unable to validate your application. - (null)warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid.

This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier:

Answer (score 0):

This means that your previous provisioning profile/s has been expired. Go to Developers portal and revoke your certificate and generate new provisioning., download and install them and set xcode setting to new one.

second option: set the "valid provisioning" in "code signing" options in "Build settings" to none.

[image]

Comment: no i purchased before 2 months but i am little bit confused to set this both distribution and developer certificate to.

Comment: for distribution and developer you need seperate proviosioning profiles.

Comment: to install app, runing code using xcode use developer certificate and proviosioning.

Comment: If still error, check weather your device ID is added to the provisioning profile or not. if not the first add your device id and then re-install provisioning.